# Javascript CRUD operation for Object. how to do CRUD operation for response object

Tags: javascript

how to do CRUD operation in Javascript Object.
For example you have response object
like

```
var resObj = {
name: "john",
age: "30",
county: "USA"
}
```

How to do CURD operation for Object in Javascript

as per I know
**Object.create() or var obj = {} or new operator**
is for creating object and for assigning property for 
**Object.defineProperty() and Objecct.defineProperties()**

Comment: Welcome to SO. That question is not related to any issue and the answer can easily be found in the documentation (=googlable). I answered anyways, since you are new and we are nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Some with alternative spelling. Choose wisely or at wish.

**[C]reate:**

```
resObj = {}; // create new variable of type object
resObj.name = 'john';  // creates new property in object and assign value
```

**[R]ead:**

```
return resObj.name; // returns "john"
return resObj['name']; // returns "john"
```

**[U]pdate:**

```
resObj.name = 'jonathan'; // updates the value
resObj['name'] = 'jonathan';  // updates the value
```

**[D]elete:**

```
delete resObj.name; // deletes the name property
delete resObj['name'];  // deletes the name property
```